# Descargar archivos consecutivos en Python

Tags: python

Quisiera descargar en python multiples archivos que tienen nombre con números consecutivos, dentro de una carpeta determinada.

Por ejemplo, los archivos serían:

```
http://abc.net/xxx/yyy/zzz-1.pdf
http://abc.net/xxx/yyy/zzz-2.pdf
http://abc.net/xxx/yyy/zzz-3.pdf
.
.
.
http://abc.net/xxx/yyy/zzz-500.pdf
```

Y ponerlos en "Output/Folder" sin cambiarles el nombre

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No especificas la versión de Python, ni el sistema operativo.
Asumiendo Python3 sobre Windows,

Instala el módulo `python wget`

> C:> pip install wget

Ahora el código

```
import wget, os
os.chdir('C:\\El_Destino\\De\\Los\\Archivos')
for num in range(1, 501):
    wdir = 'http://abc.net/xxx/yyy/zzz-{}.pdf'.format(num)
    wget.download(wdir)
```

Comment: Gracias, sí funciona. Se trata de un Python 3 en Linux. Disculpa la molestia. Hay forma de que las peticiones de hacen por ejemplo, 4 o 5 a la vez, para acelerar el proceso. Y si necesito cambiar el user agent para simular otro navegador, ¿cómo podría hacerle?

Comment: Te he votado negativo ya que la pregunta del OP no muestra ningún esfuerzo y aun así le realizas la tarea.

Comment: @YemisiSCG comprendo, pero puse el código porque era algo muy sencillo, solo fueron 4+1 líneas y no se iba a entender bien en un comentario. No pasa nada, no es el primer voto negativo que me dan en una buena respuesta. Lo que si es que sugiero que las preguntas que no cumplen sean marcadas o eliminadas para que no queden abiertas a ser respondidas. Saludos.